# Is it possible to execute same liquibase for 2 applications at same time

Tags: spring, maven, liquibase, checksum, liquibase-hibernate

I have two applications needs to be deployed at same time. Both having some common code, which is in another repo. In that common repo i have liquibase file. When i start the applictaions with time gap  this liquibase is executing and not causing any issue. But I am facing a issue, when two applications started same time, Getting exceptions.

**My doubt is it possible to execute same liquibase at same time with different applications? Data base is same. And this should be done without doing any manual changes, like deleting record from changelog table manually**.

The exception am getting is as follows

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
> 1 change sets check sum
> FLIGHT-DB-CHANGELOG-SCRIPT-SDT-845.XML-v1-dev::31-10-2022-IGE-6388::.....@.......com is now: 7:27d219f2f30604542a4a458c891cdbc7

Please help me out. Thank you

Comment: That is particular changeset issue, would you mind providing it's text?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov in that I have written a select query that's it. This issue came when i deployed two applications at same time. Can you please tell me Is it possible deploy two applications with same liquibase with same changeset at same time?

Comment: The concurrency (Liquibase handles concurrent database changes by using the databasechangeloglock and running the changes serially) should not allow for both to be executed at the same time. 
* https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/tracking-tables/databasechangeloglock-table.html?Highlight=changeloglock